# Extract Custom Metadata (XMP) From Google Drive Image using Advanced Drive Service

Tags: google-apps-script, metadata, xmp

I'm attempting to get some extra metadata added by a camera that does not seem to be available in the [ImageMediaMetaData](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files#imageMediaMetadata) resource for Google Drive. Here is the way I am currently retrieving metadata:

```
function getPhotoExif( fileId ) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var metaData = file.imageMediaMetadata;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(metaData));
  // If metaData is 'undefined', return an empty object
  return metaData ? metaData : {};
}
```

The image metadata returned is:

```
{
"date":"2019:11:09 14:11:09",
"whiteBalance":"Manual",
"subjectDistance":0,
"height":3956,
"meteringMode":"CenterWeightedAverage",
"cameraModel":"FC6520",
"isoSpeed":200,
"cameraMake":"DJI",
"exposureTime":0.01,
"exposureBias":1.65625,
"colorSpace":"sRGB",
"flashUsed":false,
"rotation":0,
"maxApertureValue":1.69,
"aperture":8,
"width":5280,
"location":{
"altitude":131.602,
"latitude":33.43046261111111,
"longitude":-117.19567805555556
},
"exposureMode":"Auto",
"focalLength":45
}
```

Those values are all documented in the file resource on Google's docs. This leads me to believe that any "custom" metadata that aren't those values will not be listed. [Using an online tool like this one](https://www.get-metadata.com/result/9a02d959-fdad-42c0-a5e6-8543b29d28f5) will show me the metadata I need, notably the Gimbal (pitch/roll/yaw) data.

Is this just not possible with Google scripts currently?

Comment: It appears that what you require isn't currently supported. However, it might be possible to create a custom parser to extract that information from your images. Finding ways to use the Drive Advanced service to extract image file headers would be a good place to start I'd think.

Comment: Thanks. What would be a good place to start? Processing the blob or byte array of the image?

Comment: That seems as good a place to start as any. What's type of image files do you need to parse? If you know that, you can look up the specification for the file format and figure out the structure of the file header.

Comment: It may be easier to help you if you provide a sample image with the metadata you are trying to access. This properties are not standard EXIF data, still, the data will probably be on uploaded file, and it should be possible to retrieve them easily, but we first need to see an example of what you are looking for.